# EditText Field Is Crashing My Android App

Tags: android

Hi all i have updated my post to show the full xml file, which will show if i am doing something wrong.

i implemented a custom dialog with an edit text field and it keeps crashing. I will
 also like to access the values filled in the text field. Any idea where i am going wrong? Thanks.

Below is the offending/troublesome??? code

First i show the xml file which contains my layout for the alert dialog.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_height="200px">

   <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <EditText 
   android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="blah"
    />
   </ScrollView>

 <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
 android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:text="Cancel" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Then main activity file which implements
 my button click events...etc.
          .......

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //this button will show the dialog
    Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01main);

    button1main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View OnClickListener) {
            //set up dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MoredialogActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
            dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);



            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            text.setText(R.string.lots_of_text);

            //set up image view
            ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

            //set up button
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //finish();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Hi! A couple of things, could you post the error log of the exception you're getting? Also, it would help to accept some answers as more people will be compelled to answer your question.

Comment: Paste the whole XML... my guess is that you are adding more than one element inside `ScrollView`

Comment: Ok...i have done soo...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two items in your ScrollView. According to the doc :

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be
>   a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

So you should had another layout, like a linear layout :

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
   android:layout_height="200px">
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center">
      <TextView
         android:text="@+id/TextView01"
         android:id="@+id/TextView01"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/lastname"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="blah" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks Zoleas..it still errored out with this output in logcat:W/dalvikvm(  447): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  447): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  447): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  447):        at com.nicee.moredialog.MoredialogActivity$1.onClick(MoredialogActivity.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(  447):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)

Comment: What is the line 36 on your MoredialogActivity ?